How can I adapt and active the Sidebar menu fomantic-ui?
How can I adapt the Sidebar fomantic-ui?
My Sidebar fomantic-ui not active.
If i click menu button it's not active.
I'm trying to create a Django . HTML design from the navigation bar made by hand and the rest of the content to design based on ready-made styles - fomantic-ui.com.
I would like, if possible, to try to somehow integrate the menu bar into the style system. I'm still a beginner. I mainly do logic in Django, and for the interface, blocks are something similar to fomantic-ui.com - ready-made style systems.
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sidebar Menu | Side Navigation Bar</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <!-- You MUST include jQuery 3.4+ before Fomantic -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.9.3/dist/semantic.min.css">
  </head>
  <body hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
    <div class="ui top attached demo menu">
      <a class="item">
        <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
        Menu
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached segment pushable">
      <div class="ui inverted labeled icon left inline vertical sidebar menu" style="">
        <a class="item">
          <i class="home icon"></i>
          Home
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          <i class="block layout icon"></i>
          Topics
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          <i class="smile icon"></i>
          Friends
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          <i class="calendar icon"></i>
          History
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="pusher">
        <div class="ui basic segment">
          <h3 class="ui header">Application Content</h3>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      // using context
      $('.context.example .ui.sidebar')
        .sidebar({
          context: $('.context.example .bottom.segment')
        })
        .sidebar('attach events', '.context.example .menu .item')
      ;
    </script>

    <script src="{% static "script/script.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.9.3/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples

